# Setting Environment variables in C# that persist after execution is complete

Tags: c#

I need to setup an environment variable from a C# program so batch files that run later can use this newly created variable.  I have tried using:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("USRNAM", "My Name", 
                                    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

After this statement I have a breakpoint setup and when it gets to this breakpoint, I go to a Command Prompt, issue the following command:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>SET USRNAM
```

I get:

```
Environment variable USRNAM not defined.
```

How can I set an Environment variable that persists after the C# program execution has completed?

Suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine?  I'm pretty sure .Process sets it temporarily just for the running process.

Answer (score 13):

Try to use either `EnvironmentVariableTarget.User` or `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine`, depending on whether you'd like the variable to be created for the current user or for all users.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget.aspx) for information on that enumeration.

Comment: I tried both but the variable was not in the SET list when I checked from the command window.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Note that you should open a new command prompt after the statement runs, I don't think an existing prompt will be able to see the new variable.