# How to set Environment variables permanently in C#

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I am using the following code to get and set environment variables.

```
public static string Get( string name, bool ExpandVariables=true ) {
    if ( ExpandVariables ) {
        return System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable( name );
    } else {
        return (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey( @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\" ).GetValue( name, "", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames );
    }
}

public static void Set( string name, string value ) {
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable( name, value );
}
```

The problem I face, is even when the program is running as administrator, the environment variable lasts only as long as the program is running. I have confirmed this by running a Get on the variable I set in a previous instance.

Example usage of above

```
Set("OPENSSL_CONF", @"c:\openssl\openssl.cfg");
```

And to retrieve

```
MessageBox.Show( Get("OPENSSL_CONF") );
```

While the program is running, after using `Set`, the value is returned using `Get` without any issue. The problem is the environment variable isn't permanent (being set on the system).

It also never shows up under advanced properties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To make them persist, you need to set the system variable, currently you are just setting process specific variable, which are bound to exist only during program duration

Comment: If you are just fetching the variable from registry to set the environment variable, then why not use it directly, why would you want to set it as Environment variable at all. It would make sense only when you are dynamically setting stuff (registry stuff is almost static) and want it to persist beyond. Also what after setting registry value change ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> While the program is running, after using Set, the value is returned
>   using Get without any issue. The problem is the environment variable
>   isn't permanent (being set on the system).

Thats because the overload of `SetEnvironmentVariable` that you're using stores in the *process* variables. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Calling this method is equivalent to calling the
>   SetEnvironmentVariable(String, String, EnvironmentVariableTarget)
>   overload with a value of **EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process** for the
>   target argument.

You need to use the overload specifying [`EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environmentvariabletarget(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
public static void Set(string name, string value) 
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(name, value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
}
```

Comment: Itchakov, do you know if there are any specific permissions required for using `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine`?

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN the method you are using is just modifying the variable for the runtime of the process.

Try the overload described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/96xafkes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This kind of question has already been asked multiple times, check the following links for more information:

[Set Env Variable - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872190/setting-environment-variables-in-c-sharp-that-persist-after-execution-is-complet)

[Set Env Variable - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774358/c-sharp-set-environment-variable)

[Set Env Variable - Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/178713-working-with-environment-variables-in-c%23/)

Comment: Also remember, Env variables are always inherited on the process beginning, so cannot be Get when process is already on , this needs restart

Comment: not sure why none of those results appeared when i search here, google, and the 'auto' search while writing the article.  epic 3 x fail for search engines ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that permanently updates the User PATH variable by programmatically editing the registry:

```
// Admin Permission not-required:
//      HKCU\Environment\Path
// Admin Permission required:
//      HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
//         \Session Manager\Environment\Path

public static void UserPathAppend(string path, int verbose=1) {
    string oldpath = UserPathGet();

    List<string> newpathlist = oldpath.Split(';').ToList();
    newpathlist.Add(path);

    string newpath = String.Join(";", newpathlist.ToArray());

    UserPathSet(newpath);

    UpdateEnvPath();

    if (verbose!=0) {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
            "PATH APPEND:\n\n"
            + path + "\n\n"
            + "OLD HKCU PATH:\n\n"
            +  oldpath + "\n\n"
            + "NEW HKCU PATH:\n\n"
            +  newpath + "\n\n"
            + "REGISTRY KEY MODIFIED:\n\n"
            + "HKCU\\Environment\\Path\n\n"
            + "NOTE:\n\n"
            + "'Command Path' is a concat of 'HKLM Path' & 'HKCU Path'.\n",
            "Updated Current User Path Environment Variable"
        );
    }
}

public static void UserPathPrepend(string path, int verbose=1) {
    string oldpath = UserPathGet();

    List<string> newpathlist = oldpath.Split(';').ToList();
    newpathlist.Insert(0, path);

    string newpath = String.Join(";", newpathlist.ToArray());

    UserPathSet(newpath);

    UpdateEnvPath();

    if (verbose != 0) {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
            "PATH PREPEND:\n\n"
            + path + "\n\n"
            + "OLD HKCU PATH:\n\n"
            +  oldpath + "\n\n"
            + "NEW HKCU PATH:\n\n"
            +  newpath + "\n\n"
            + "REGISTRY KEY MODIFIED:\n\n"
            + "HKCU\\Environment\\Path\n\n"
            + "NOTE:\n\n"
            + "'Command Path' is a concat of 'HKLM Path' & 'HKCU Path'.\n",
            "Updated Current User Path Environment Variable"
        );
    }
}

public static string UserPathGet()
{
    // Reads Registry Path "HKCU\Environment\Path"
    string subKey = "Environment";

    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey sk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(subKey);

    if (sk == null)
        return null;
    else
        return sk.GetValue("Path").ToString();
}

public static void UserPathSet(string newpath)
{
    // Writes Registry Path "HKCU\Environment\Path"
    string subKey = "Environment";

    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey sk1 = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(subKey);
    sk1.SetValue("Path", newpath);
}

//===========================================================
// Private: This part required if you don't want to logout 
//          and login again to see Path Variable update
//===========================================================

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, 
            uint Msg, UIntPtr wParam, string lParam, 
            SendMessageTimeoutFlags fuFlags, 
            uint uTimeout, out UIntPtr lpdwResult);

private enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
{
    SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0, SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1, 
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2, SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8
}

private static void UpdateEnvPath() {
    // SEE: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/104011/how-to-propagate-environment-variables-to-the-system
    // Need to send WM_SETTINGCHANGE Message to 
    //    propagage changes to Path env from registry
    IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = (IntPtr)0xffff;
    const UInt32 WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A;
    UIntPtr result;
    IntPtr settingResult
        = SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST,
                             WM_SETTINGCHANGE, (UIntPtr)0,
                             "Environment",
                             SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,
                             5000, out result);
}
```